# Cannot send empty message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, client

```
DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\hadak\Desktop\» Discord┃Qurantäne\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\hadak\Desktop\» Discord┃Qurantäne\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:14)
    at async TextChannel.send (C:\Users\hadak\Desktop\» Discord┃Qurantäne\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:171:15)
    at async Object.execute (C:\Users\hadak\Desktop\» Discord┃Qurantäne\commands\reaction-roles.js:18:29) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/884122293343764491/messages',
  code: 50006,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      content: undefined,
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: undefined,
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

Code:

```js
const {
  MessageEmbed
} = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: 'reaction-roles',
  description: 'Das ist ein Verify Command',
  async execute(client, message, args, Discord) {
    if (!message.member.roles.cache.has('883408339525070919')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the role! Huanson');

    const channel = '884122293343764491'
    const verifyRole = '884122984095285268'
    const verifySymbol = '✔️'

    let embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("GREEN")
      .setTitle('React to Verify')
      .setDescription('React with ✔️ to get Verified')

    let messagesEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed)
    messagesEmbed.react(verifySymbol)

    client.on('messageReactionAdd', async(reaction, user) => {
      if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
      if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
      if (user.bot) return;
      if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

      if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
        if (reaction.emooji.name === verifySymbol) {
          await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(verifyRole);

        }
      } else {
        return;
      }
    });
    client.on('messageReactionRemove', async(reaction, user) => {
      if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
      if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
      if (user.bot) return;
      if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

      if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
        if (reaction.emooji.name === verifySymbol) {
          await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(verifyRole);

        }
      } else {
        return;
      }
    });


  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the [official guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-embed-constructor) you'll notice, that you have to send embeds like this:

```js
let embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("GREEN")
      .setTitle('React to Verify')
      .setDescription('React with ✔️ to get Verified')

await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
```

Comment: Cool it works, thanks but i have another problem now i dont get the Role

Comment: If the current issue is solved, give the answer a checkmark. For a new issue create a new post